# Xcode debug watch @Published as expresion

Tags: swiftui

I have a published property in SwiftUI declared thus:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class UserData: ObservableObject  {

    @Published var showLoginButton = true
```

In the debugger at a breakpoint I cannot see the value of this property. I can see the value of properties that are not decorated as `@Published`.

[image: xcode screenshot showing @Published property without value]

What expression do I need to see the current value of a published property when debugging SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3):

`@Published` is a property wrapper, so you see its storage. To get value just print property, so here it is

```
(lldb) e _showLoginButton
(Published<Bool>) $R0 = {}
(lldb) e self.showLoginButton
(Bool) $R2 = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your source code (tests included) includes `import Combine`. In the Xcode debugger you can then use the `print description` button (icon is a circle with an 'i' in the center) to view the current value. Without the import the console will show `"error: cannot find type 'Combine' in scope"`.